# Search input using a query using Vuex and Axios

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm trying to make a search input where I input a query and that query gets added to the API call and returns me the data that I want, here's a sample of my code

```
      <input
    class="rounded-l-full w-full py-6 px-6 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
    id="search"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search"
    v-bind="query"
  />

    <button
      class="bg-blue-900 text-white rounded-full p-2 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none w-12 h-12 flex items-center justify-center"
      @click="getSearchResults()"
    >
      <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'search']" />
    </button>
```

My JS:

```
    <script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters, mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Main",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["searchResult"]),
    ...mapState({
      query: (state) => state.query,
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getSearchResults"]),
  },
};
</script>
```

My vuex module:

```
    import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  results: [],
  query: "",
};

const getters = {
  searchResult: (state) => state.results,
};

const actions = {
  async getSearchResults() {
    let query = state.query;
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=${query}`
    );

    res.data.artists.forEach((artist) => state.results.push(artist));
  },
};

const mutations = {
  returnResults: (state, results) => (state.results = results),
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

The search query is not getting passed on the input, if I put something on the query from the Vuex module I get the correct results but if I input something and click the search button I get the default results of the api JSON which means my input is not working, I'd appreciate some help and thanks in advance!

Comment: something about the face that `query` is *computed* doesn't look right

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried using it on data doing like "query: this.$store.state.query" but that didn't work either. I been googling for hours I'm not sure what to do

Comment: perhaps https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Comment: @JaromandaX tried that earlier did not work either

Comment: maybe you did it wrong - seems like that should work

Comment: @JaromandaX could you show me a code example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that your using v-bind incorrectly, better use v-model:

```
<input
    class="rounded-l-full w-full py-6 px-6 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
    id="search"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search"
    v-model="query"
  />
```

second thing organize better your code when you are using vuex, I would do it of this way:

Template:

```
// pass the variable query to the funcion getSearchResults
<button
      class="bg-blue-900 text-white rounded-full p-2 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none w-12 h-12 flex items-center justify-center"
      @click="getSearchResults(query)"
    >
      <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'search']" />
    </button>
```

JS:

```
// Only import mapActions and mapGetters
// create the variable query inside of data() for v-model
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters} from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Main",
  data() {
    return {
         query:"",
      };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["searchResult"]),
   
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getSearchResults"]),
  },
};
</script>
```

VUEX:

```
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  results: [],
};

const getters = {
  searchResult: (state) => state.results,
};

const actions = {
  async getSearchResults({commit}, query) {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=${query}`
    );
    // Execute the mutation which receive the data and pass to the state
    commit('returnResults', res.data.artists)
  },
};

const mutations = {
  returnResults: (state, results) => (state.results = results),
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

Comment: @sleepydev No Problem.